# How can I count unique views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a tricky problem to solve. I need to be able to track how many unique views to a URL (that includes a promo code): www.mysite.com/hello/PROMO

The issues are:

1. Since I pay for views based on promo code, I want to make sure people can't fake views.
2. It's difficult for me to count views from the same IP as fraudulent, because a lot of my users are on college campuses (i.e. behind the same NAT, often using one of a handful of IP addresses).

Any ideas on how I can have a robust view tracking system, given my concerns re IP repeats amongst my users?

FYI - I am using Ruby on Rails.

Edit - My site uses Google Analytics, so I'm wondering how accurate GA is at determining unique visitors to a specific URL (and whether the API is capable of giving me that result).

Comment: You might want to edit your question a bit to provide more context. You don't mention Google Analytics in your question, but you have two GA related tags. Are you asking how to get what you want with Google Analytics, or are you just asking how to track unique visits/views to a page in a Rails app?

Comment: added - I use GA so I wanted to give context that I can use GA / GA API for this (but I have no way of measuring how accurate they are).

Comment: You can look at gems like impressionist, analytics-rails, etc., of which there are many. Regardless of your choice, your question is very broad and there's no way to give you a precise answer because ultimately, it's going to be up to you to decide what constitutes a valid unique visit.

Comment: Unique view = unique individual visiting the page for the first time. Does that help clarify?